# Recursion function yielding infinite loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, infinite-loop

I'm having some major problems using recursion functions to generate a simple table. My goal is to generate a table in HTML that outputs a different row for each possible combination of elements in my sub arrays:

```
var paras = [
 [1, 2, 3],
 ["a", "b", "c"],
 //[7, 8, 9], //WARNING!!! UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE WILL RESULT IN AN INFINITE LOOP
 //['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'],
 //['6"', '12"', '18"'],
 //["316SS"],
 //["Grounded", "Ungrounded", "Exposed"],
];
```

For example, in the above array I would like to generate something along the lines of:

```
1a7
1a8
1a9
1b7
1b8
1b9
1c7...
3c9
```

Eventually I'd like that to be output into a table in HTML but for now all I care about is basically getting that pattern generated anyway that I can.

Now for the hard part. I can't use nested for loops. It would be easy to have 3 loops nested in each other each going from 1 to the length of the particular subarray, but what about when i have 4 subarrays, or 10, or 1000. I'd like the code to be independent of how many subarrays, and how many variables in each sub array, there are.

```
var numcats = paras.length;
var retStack = [];
var retQ = [];



function genTable(array1) {
  if (array1.length == 1) { //if there is only 1 sub-array (base case)
    if (array1[0].length == 1) { //if that array contains only 1 element
      retStack.push(array1[0][0]);
      return retStack;
    } else {
      var temp = array1;
      var item = temp[0].pop();
      retStack = genTable(temp);
      retStack.push(item);
      return retStack; //returns 1 2 3 when there is only 1 sub array
    }
  } else {
    var tempParas = array1;
    var topArray = tempParas.pop();
    var permQ = genTable(tempParas);
    for (i = 0; i < topArray.length; i++) {
      var tempQ = [];
      var tempQ = permQ;
      while (tempQ.length >= 1) {
        retQ.push(topArray[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < tempParas.length; j++) {
          retQ.push(tempQ.pop());
        }
      }
    }
    return retQ; //returns a 3 a 2 a 1 when there are 2 sub-arrays
  }
}

console.log(genTable(paras))
```

My problems:

- When i have 2 subarrays (as shown above) the return is a 3 a 2 a 1. I might be able to fix the reverse order problem by using shift instead of pop? But why does it not go on to b and c.
- When i have 3 or more subarrays I get trapped in an infinite loop (i believe the while loop isn't breaking because the variable in the condition isn't defining correctly? maybe..?

Here is my jsfiddle if you want to see my actual code (pretty much the same but messier as it has lots of console.logs to help me debug) - http://jsfiddle.net/wmkNe/206/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is Array Recursion. This will iterate through all of the arrays in your `paras` variable.

I have updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98oL12tk/1/)

```
var paras = [
  [1, 2, 3],
 ["a", "b", "c"],
 [7, 8, 9], //WARNING!!! UNCOMMENTING THIS LINE WILL RESULT IN AN INFINITE LOOP
 ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'],
 ['6"', '12"', '18"'],
 ["316SS"],
 ["Grounded", "Ungrounded", "Exposed"],
];

function arrayRecursion(paras) {
  if (paras.length == 1) 
    return paras[0];

  var results = [];
  var allValues = arrayRecursion(paras.slice(1));
  for (var i = 0; i < allValues.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < paras[0].length; j++) {
      results.push(paras[0][j] + allValues[i]);
    }
  }
  return results;    
}

console.log(arrayRecursion(paras));
```

This returns results as:
["1a71/8"6"316SSGrounded", "2a71/8"6"316SSGrounded", "3a71/8"6"316SSGrounded", "1b71/8"6"316SSGrounded", "2b71/8"6"316SSGrounded",...]

Comment: Wow, yours is so much simpler, and it' almost perfect. For some reason it doesn't work for me for my 4th array. Also it doesn't work when there are 2 arrays in a row that are both filled with numbers because it adds the numbers together, rather than concatenating them. Do I have to define all of my elements as strings in the arrays? or is there someway to have them be converted to strings in the function?

Comment: To prevent the numbers from being added, you can force the values to be parsed as strings...
var allValues = arrayRecursion(paras.slice(1).toString());

Comment: that would generate ["1a,b,c,7,8,9", "2a,b,c,7,8,9", "3a,b,c,7,8,9"] where only the first element of each group follows the pattern =/, unless i did that wrong

Comment: You're quite correct. I will take another look at the method in a few minutes. Stuck in a meeting at the moment.

Comment: I have forked your original fiddle and everything seems to be working as expected now. Let me know if this is still misbehaving and I will take another look at it.  http://jsfiddle.net/98oL12tk/1/

Comment: That looks great thanks! is there a way to get the elements to be output as separate elements within a sub array? for example instead of element 1 being a string "1a71/8"6"316SSGrounded", for it to be a sub array with each value being its own element/string. i.e. element 1 would be ["1","a","7",'1/8"','6"',"316SS","Grounded"]. That way I could access 316SS as the 6th subelement of my first element. If that's not possible, that's okay, i should be able to make do with what I have

Comment: I'm sure it is. I will revisit the code as soon as I have a few free minutes.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate it. I've been working with what you gave me and updating the jsfiddle. To give you an idea of what my end goal is you can take a look at it http://jsfiddle.net/98oL12tk/7/ - It's obviously much harder for you to edit in that form so I'm happy working with the fiddle you posted earlier, but I just wanted to show you the direction I'm headed in case I'm going about it wrong. I'm trying to fill in that table with the different values which is why I had asked if this format ["1","a","7",'1/8"','6"',"316SS","Grounded"] was possible, or even necessary.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it - not sure if it's optimal from a programming stand point but it works. Here's a jsfiddle incase anyone in the future needs it http://jsfiddle.net/98oL12tk/8/

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this I'm thinking this is like counting in a base system using different base and symbols per position:

```
function getCounter(arrSymbols) {
  const arrSymbolsReversed = arrSymbols.reverse();
  return n => arrSymbolsReversed
    .reduce((o, s) => ({str:  s[o.n % s.length]+o.str, n: Math.floor(o.n / s.length)}), {str:"",n:n})
    .str;
}
var count = getCounter([['1','2','3'],['a','b','c'],['7','8','9']]);
_.range(0,27).map(count); //=> ["1a7", "1a8", ...]
```

Comment: Basically, yes it just a counting problem where each digit is in a different base. Sorry I'm not super experienced with this stuff but It's having problems with the _.range line, am I supposed to be filling in that blank?

also i want it to work for all sizes so would i have to generate the 27 by multiplying all the lengths of the arrays together?

Comment: @MatthewSirkin No it's underscore. `_.range(0,27)` is underscore library function that creates an array `[0...26]`.